# How to make correct prediction for same ID with different values

Tags: python, machine-learning

I can't find info how to make correct prediction 
for the following data frame:

---

```
train data:

id   variable   value    statement 

1       x1        431       1
1       x2        11        1
1       x3        65        1
2       x1        33        0
2       x2        2         0
3       x3        58        1
3       x1        22        1
.
.
.
```

---

```
need to predict:

id   variable      value    statement 

996       x1        431        ?
996       x2        131        ?
997       x3        62         ?
997       x1        33         ?
997       x2        23         ?
998       x1        18         ?
999       x1        26         ?
```

im wondering what to do if i get different statement for same id, for example:

```
 id         statement 

 997           0.66
 997           0.95
 997           0.34
```

what should i do in this case, should i groupby ID and get maximum, or it will be some average... what would be the right choice?
thanks...

Answer (score 0):

@Андрей Алексеевич I would say it depends what ID means in your DF.

Most of the time, the ID isn't taking into account while predicting due to the fact that you"ll have to many ID and ID isn't really a number.

Therefore, you'll have to use get_dummies to split ID into different columns

```
df_ohe = pd.get_dummies(df, prefix_sep="__")
df_ohe.head()
out:
id_0   id_1   id_2 ...
 0      1     0 
 0      0     1
 1      0     0
```

To sum up:

- if the ID is really a ID (such as one id per contrat), I would drop this feature.
- if the ID gives some useful information, such as id 1 = big customer, id2 = medium customer... I would keep this feature and split it with get_dummies.

**EDIT with your question**

@Андрей Алексеевич

Let's say each ID represents a client (id 1 = client 1, ...)

If you keep this feature, and you will try to predict if the client smokes (YES or NO). Your model will learn (kind of overfitting) that the client id 1 is a smoker and so on.

Therefore, your model will not really generalize as well to your new data (new clients to which you do not know if they smoke or not)

Furthermore as I said, ID are not number (even if it's written 0,1,2,..). If you keep them, the model will interpret those id as numbers. Thus, it will say, id 100 > id 20 and so on.

Comment: ID is real ID. for example same ID has many different variables with values, and we have some statement, for example 1 (the customer is smoker) and 0 (not smoker). and we will have same id with different Var and Val which will give few different statement, how to choose statement from many others for same id

Comment: how can you drop it? its the only important thing here.. depending on that data we need to find out if the customer is smoker, if we drop it we will not know)

Comment: @Андрей Алексеевич answer edited with your question

Comment: looks like you misunderstood me a little bit, i will try to be clearer: i don't want to include ID as a data to build a model, but same ID has a few different variables so it will get a few different results. The question was how to choose correct prediction if same person has few different results?